# iOS Swift how to make textview/label on left hand side of a view and if there are too many text, it goes under the right view

Tags: swift, textview

Like the title said, I want to make textview or label on left hand side of a view and if there are too many text, it goes under the right view
Please check the attached image for illustration

[image]

You can see on the right, there's a rounded corner view with text & button, and the left is text, and because there are too much text, so some goes under the image view and cross to the right side under the image view.
I was thinking: calculating the height of the string & split the text into 2 labels if necessary. Is there any better way?

Comment: iOS or macOS? Have you looked into any possible solutions yet? Have you done any research into including an image in a text view?

Comment: I should clarify, it's not an imageview on the right, it's a view

Comment: and it's for iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found an attribute: exclusion path on UITextView which solve my problem